# How to access or parse key/values that have "string"

Tags: php, array, variables, parse

Coming from a Perl background (no snickering) and trying to make sense of some new conventions. Not sure whether this is a PHP, WordPress, or Ninja forms question.

`$form_data //Ninja parlance` contains:

```
["value"] => string(8) "John Smith"
["key"]=> string(33) "first_and_last_name_1570130204042"
```

So when I test for a key, it's seeing:

```
string(33) "first_and_last_name_1570130204042"
```

Of course, I'm not interested in

```
string(33)
```

but in it's 'name' (not sure what it's called)

```
first_and_last_name_1570130204042
```

How do I get, in essence:

```
$form_data['key'] = "first_and_last_name_1570130204042"
```

without a lot of `preg_matches` ?

If it were JSON I'd be fine. Read about `unserialize` but that doesn't seem to be the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

In it's current state you would directly get the value from the associative PHP array by directly referencing the key like so:

```
var_dump( $form_data['key'] );
```

It's wise to note that when you dump variables using `var_dump` you get information on the value type, and length. So in this case you get `string(33)` which indicates the value is a string and is 33 characters long. This is purely informational and this isn't stored or otherwise interfering with your actual data.

For example if you simply `echo` that array key instead of using `var_dump`, you will get the value:

```
echo $form_data['key'];
```

You would get `first_and_last_name_1570130204042`.

You may find some of the documentation on W3 Schools useful if you're still adjusting to PHP from Perl. Here's the relevant links to support the above:

- [PHP Datatypes / var_dumps](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_datatypes.asp)
- [Echo and Print things in PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp)
- [PHP
  Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

If you're more at home with JSON, you can actually convert a PHP array with the function `$json_data = json_encode( $form_data )` too

Comment: Brilliant. I've only been using `var_dump` and wasn't aware of all that it "dumped." Dumper Beware. I'll check out the links, and consider a JSON route.

Comment: @breadwild if this answers your question I'd massively appreciate if you accepted it as the answer, would love me some profile points in return for my time :)

Comment: Well, I massively appreciate your answer, but I don't have enough reputation to vote, apparently